# Is there a ready-to-use form to display lists of objects in the django forms api?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Is there a form(or any other solution) that allows me to quickly build forms that display lists of models(with filtering, ordering etc) like the django admin site does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: [Yes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list).

Long answer: Yes, but the filtering, ordering, etc. are left up to you to come up with. In Django "generic view" really does mean generic.